# How to manage Disk-Utilization on a PS3?

Tags: ps3

I got a Disk-Full error on downloading a preview. How can I find out how many free capacity is on disk and how can I free it up?

Is there a possibility to delete some old update files or something like that, or is there a kind of diskmanager availabe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see your available capacity by going to System Settings -> System Information. It's near the bottom, so you'll have to scroll down to see it.

The easiest way to clean up space on your PS3 is to remove some of the game data files (these are not the savegames, these are files that are cached on the hard drive to make the game run smoothly).  These can be deleted from the Game Data Utility folder. If you decide later that you want to play that game again, it's not a problem -- the game will reinstall automatically.

Comment: That sounds nice but is there anything else?

Comment: You could also remove savegames to free up disk space, or delete any games that you've downloaded. Those are all manual, though -- as far as I know, there's not a utility or anything that would take care of it for you automatically.

Comment: When you have any content selected in the main menu, hit Triangle, then pick "Information".  One of the fields displayed should include the size of the item -- this will help you pick what to delete.